# Questions about "Nandroid" backups

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 5.0-lollipop, backup, nexus-4, nandroid

I have a nexus 4 and I'm having issues with Android 5.0 so I was thinking to go back to 4.4.4, but first I want to backup the current state.

Before I do this, I have a few questions:

- if create a full nandroid backup with Nexus Root Toolkit, then Flash 4.4.4 + unroot, then change my mind and restore the backup, will the Phone be in precisely the same state as before? Meaning Android 5.0, same apps installed, no lost config etc. ?
- can i switch between backups as I please without any side effects? Like restore a 4.4.4 backup, then restore a 5.0 backup ...
- can the contents from these backups be visualized on the computer?

thanks

Comment: Don't know how Nexus Root Toolkit takes the backup bit I would recommend TWRP/Philz to take Nandroid backup. Note that you *may* (I don't know so verify it) need to flash other firmware partitions as well to go back to Kitkat. // Yes, if you restore the backup all your Android settings and apps would be there, that's what backup literally means. // Yes, you can revert from one backup to another (but as I said, do verify the need of flashing rest of the firmware). // The only downside I see is flash storage have limited number of write cycles so if your device is already aging then go easy.

Answer (score 0):

Good Thing you don t have a Samsung (KNOX wont let you easily downgrade).

To answer you questions to a certain extent:

- depending on how you did your nandroid backup 
  it won't be "precisely" the same (e.g. most users dont backup the Cache).
- no, but maybe you don't want the "EZ-backup and Restore" procedure - Sounds to me like you would like a "dual boot" maybe? If so see this thread:
  http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-4/orig-development/mod-multirom-v24-t2472295
- define "visualized", you could copy the backup to pc and see the backup files. is that what you mean?